# localhost redirected you too many times. laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I checked with the guards, but they are set perfectly. The problem I figured out is stated below. 
This is custom guard

```
Route::get('user/login', 'user\Authuser\userLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('user.login');  //this works fine 

Route::name('user.')->prefix('/user')->namespace('user')->group(function(){
   Route::namespace('Authuser')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/login','userLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');  //this give error, localhost redirected you too many times
    });
});
```

Comment: Please explain what you've tried to debug the problem

Answer (score 0):

After you login , means that you are authenticated, then you should access the rest of your endpoints.

Laravel has an easy implementation for that using `Auth` middleware.

Having said that your routes should look like:

```
Route::get('user/login', 'user\Authuser\userLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('user.login'); 


Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::name('user.')->prefix('/user')->namespace('user')->group(function(){
        Route::namespace('Authuser')->group(function(){
            Route::get('/login','userLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');  //this give error, localhost redirected you too many times
        });
    });
});
```

Inside this group you can add all your application endpoints, that require authentication.